# How to use jQuery with PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to scrape websites with PhantomJS, I need to perform some operation on websites. I would like to use jQuery for that. I've created following code

```
page.open(url, function (status)
    {
        if (status === "success")
        {
            page.injectJs('jquery-1.11.1.min.js');

            var links = page.evaluate(function()
            {
                 $jq = window.jQuery;
                 $jq.noConflict();

                 var links = [];

                 $jq('a').each(function()
                 {

                 });

                 return links;
            }); 

        }
    });
```

Sometimes it crashes.

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'jQuery('.some-div-one-the-scrapering-page')

Probably jQuery is already used on this site, a version different from mine. How can I fix it? Do I have to use plain JS?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to correspond with the code you provided. There is no class selector used.

Comment: The error is from website, which I am trying to scrape. This website is using jQuery either and there is a conflict beetween 2 different version of library, I guess.

Comment: Then why do you want to use your own version?

Comment: I am scraping a lot of websites and not every one has jQuery. They can have sometimes very old version and I need to have guaranty thay everything works as I expected. I can use plain js but jQuery is just convenient at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the page already has jQuery, use `window.jQuery`:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
    page.injectJs('jquery-1.11.1.min.js');
}
```

This way, if the page already has jQuery loaded, your script won't try to load it again. Otherwise, it will carry out the `page.injectJs('jquery-1.11.1.min.js')`

Comment: That won't work in PhantomJS, unfortunately. `window` and `page` exist in different contexts.